# How to disable scenario wise log generation in karate

Tags: log4j, karate

I need help on disabling the log file generation for each scenarios in feature file. Here please find the below log4j xml

%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        
    
  
    
        target/karate.log
        
            %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n

Comment: not supported. whatever is supported is in the link, if you want please contribute code